# Getting API Response using Guzzle in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to get a response from the Metals API but keep getting 404 errors even though I can get the API using the URL.

```
    public function valueFromApi(){

    $accesskey = "123456";
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://metals-api.com/api/latest', [
        'form_params' => [
            'access_key' => $accesskey,
            'base' => 'GBP',
            'symbols' => 'XAU',]
]);

dd($response);

}
```

If I try and access the URL directly through a browser this works:

```
https://metals-api.com/api/latest?access_key=123456&base=GBP&symbols=XAU
```

I must have misunderstood the way the parameters are working. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form params is not the same as query parameters. Therefor you need to set the parameters as query. If you are accessing this in the browser, i would not expect it to be a POST but a GET.

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://metals-api.com/api/latest', [
    RequestOptions::QUERY => [
        'access_key' => $accesskey,
        'base' => 'GBP',
        'symbols' => 'XAU',
    ]
]);
```

I am using the RequestOptions, this is syntaxic sugar for the hardcoded string options, the same as 'query'.

Comment: Thanks that worked but I also added "use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions"

Comment: Ofc that is implicit in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As specified in their [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params), you need to define the constant

```
    define("form_params", GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS );
```

Then you can use your code

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://metals-api.com/api/latest', [
        'form_params' => [
            'access_key' => $accesskey,
            'base' => 'GBP',
            'symbols' => 'XAU',]
]);
```